# How can I do float:right in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form that displays the username onload. In the right side of the form there is a label which is Welcome and the linklabel for the username

It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is when the username is too long, it goes beyond the border of the form. I tried setting RightToLeft to yes but still not working, I also tried setting Autosize to false and RightToLeft and it seems to work for the linklabel but the problem this time is that it overlaps the Welcome label or vise versa,

How should I set the label and linklabel to adjust from right to left side whatever the lenght of the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use a separate Label control to display "Welcome".  The LinkLabel control allows you to mix text and hyperlinks with its LinkArea property.  So just keep it a single control, anchor it to the Top+Right, AutoSize = false, TextAlign = TopRight and make it wide enough to fit Mr. Llanfairpwllgwyngyll.

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        string prefix = "Welcome ";
        linkLabel1.Text = prefix + Environment.UserName;
        linkLabel1.LinkArea = new LinkArea(prefix.Length, linkLabel1.Text.Length - prefix.Length);
    }
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a *long* time since I did anything with Windows Forms, but I seem to remember [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)s as being awesome for this kind of thing.

It's pretty straight-forward in the designer to get one set up, but essentially you'll want four columns and two or three rows.

Rows:

- Just a buffer: empty, 5px absolute height
- Content: auto-height

Columns:

- Whatever is on the left: 100% width
- "Welcome" label: auto-width
- Name label: auto-width
- Buffer: 10px width

Obviously both buffers are optional, and you may want to change the size. But that's what I remember from a few years ago as being "about right" in most cases.

I don't know if there's a better way than that, but this is a pretty easy way of getting it done, and you can do a lot more with it for layouts once it's in place.

You could also use a panel with some docks, but that's a bit less extensible, for better or worse.